# How can we control trigger to fire only for some users which share same profile

Tags: apex, trigger, profile

We have a trigger on attachment, can we control the trigger firing on the basis of users who share same profile. Like through custom setting or anything.

Comment: Yes, UserInfo.getProfileId() method will give you the logged in user profile. Accordingly, you can implement conditions in your trigger code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `Profile` whitelist fairly simply. Use the `Lazy Load` pattern, and look at `Trigger Handler` patterns to find one that suits you.

```
public with sharing class MyObjectService
{
    public static Set<Id> whitelistedProfileIds
    {
        get
        {
            if (whilelistedProfileIds == null)
                whitelistedProfileIds = new Map<Id, Profile>([
                    SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name IN ('<value1>', '<value2>')
                ]).keySet();
            return whitelistedProfileIds;
        }
        private set;
    }
    public static Boolean isRunningUserWhilelisted()
    {
        return isWhitelisted(UserInfo.getProfileId());
    }
    public static Boolean isWhitelisted(Id profileId)
    {
        return whitelistedProfileIds.contains(profileId);
    }
}
```

If you adopt a `Trigger Handler` pattern, it is really simple to bail when you hit a specific condition.

```
public with sharing class MyObjectTriggerHandler
{
    final List<MyObject__c> newRecords;
    final Map<Id, MyObject__c> oldMap;
    public MyObjectTriggerHandler(List<MyObject__c> newRecords, Map<Id, MyObject__c> oldMap)
    {
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
        this.oldMap = oldMap;
    }

    public void beforeInsert()
    {
        // logic that should always run
        if (isRunningUserWhitelisted())
        {
            // logic that should only run for specific profiles
        }
    }
    public void afterInsert()
    {
        // similar pattern
    }

    // other trigger events
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a Custom Setting of list type and add Names of profiles which you want to be skipped. This custom settings can be easily configured by System Admin without updating code in future.
2. Then in trigger you can fetch values of that custom setting, to check if logged in user have that profile.